# What is the significance of a Scene ending in the Extraction mission?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

The Extraction mission notes where Scenes end, but doesn't say what happens when a scene ends.  What is the significance of even saying the Scene ends, then?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main purposes to a scene in the game and while what happens when a scene ends varies based on the mission the basics are the same. In the case of an extraction you have a set round limit instead of a number of scenes to complete. In this case the scene end does two things, first is it heals all runners and the client, second is to provide reset of certain abilities. This is in addition to the normal addition of new obstacles.

[Rules](http://cdn.shadowruntabletop.com/wp-content/uploads/CAT27700_Crossfire_Full%20Rules.pdf?c1abe8)

> Most Missions:
>
> Are divided into “Scenes” with small rewards, breaks,
>   or changes of play mode between Scenes. Each Mission
>   sheet will describe what happens during a Scene
>   and when a Scene ends.
>
> Some upgrades are usable once per Scene. Once used
>   during a Scene within a Mission, they can’t be used
>   again during that same Scene. When a Mission changes
>   from one Scene to the next, these abilities become
>   available for use again.

Answer (score 0):

I see mention of there being upgrades that are "once per scene".  This seems to be the reason for stating these boundaries.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14605)

Comment: I thought the answer I wrote was complete, actually. My research seemed to only turn up this single reason as to why they distinguish the ending of scenes when there are no mission specific scene-ended side effects.

Comment: Sorry, seems I wasn't paying attention to what I was doing when I made that comment.